# jQuery getJSON simple example

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying learn the getJSON helper and not sure what I am doing wrong.

my JS file:

```
$.getJSON('cars.json', function(d) {
    $('#span_id').append('<p> JSON Value:' + d.model + '</p>');
});
```

cars.json:

```
{
   "model":"Esperanto",
   "wheels":"4",
   "color":"blue",
...
}
```

html:

```
<body>
    <div><span id='span_id'> </span></div>
</body>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you `console.log(d)`?? or are there any errors in console?

Comment: hi yes the console is giving me an error, although i dont understand the error fully.


`XMLHttpRequest cannot load
file:///Users/c4binfever/Documents/practice_code/cars.json.
Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
send @ jquery.min.js:3
st.extend.ajax @ jquery.min.js:3
st.(anonymous function) @ jquery.min.js:3
st.extend.getJSON @ jquery.min.js:3
(anonymous function) @ seats.js:15
f @ jquery.min.js:1
p.fireWith @ jquery.min.js:1
st.extend.ready @ jquery.min.js:1
xt @ jquery.min.js:1`

Comment: That error is all important... what exactly does it say? WHen in doubt if you google the error you will almost always find something related

Comment: You are trying to open an html file that isn't being run from a server and you can't do ajax from `file://` protocol. Install a localhost server on your computer

Comment: Thanks for your help @charlietfl . I have a WAMP server I will run again from.

Answer (score 0):

from comments:

You are trying to open an html file that isn't being run from a server and you can't do ajax from file:// protocol. Install a localhost server on your computer – @charlietfl